# mysql query is not working in perl

Tags: mysql, linux, perl

I am beginner for perl developer. 
i am connecting mysql by perl script .
but when i try hit some queries. 
all queries are running successfully except one. 
and where i use that query on mysql console it runs successfully.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;

$dbh1 = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:testing;host=localhost', 'root', '93C0o35A9/692fz') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

$dbh1->do('stop slave');
$dbh1->do('CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=54.254.154.33, MASTER_USER=replica, MASTER_PASSWORD=aims145, MASTER_LOG_FILE=mysql-bin99, MASTER_LOG_POS=107');
$dbh1->do('start slave');
```

first and third queries are running fine while second one is showing syntax error as follows

```
 ./newmysql.pl
```

> DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '54.183.14.179, MASTER_USER=replica,
>   MASTER_PASSWORD=aims145, MASTER_LOG_FILE=mys' at line 1 at
>   ./newmysql.pl line 8.

[image]
Please help me here where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dbh1->do("CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=\'54.183.14.179\', MASTER_USER=\'replica\', MASTER_PASSWORD=\'aims145\', MASTER_LOG_FILE=\'$mainip[0]\', MASTER_LOG_POS=$mainip[1] ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html) recommends to quote the values of the different variables, try:

```
$dbh1->do("CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='54.254.154.33', MASTER_USER='replica', MASTER_PASSWORD='aims145', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin99', MASTER_LOG_POS=107");
```

Comment: It is perverse to use single quotes on a string that has a multitude of single quotes!

Comment: So replace the outer single-quotes with double-quotes, and then you don't need to escape the inner single-quotes.

Comment: @LenJaffe: Yes, almost *anything* else will do: `"..."`, `q{...}`, `qq/.../` but choosing the *only* special character that appears in the string is a big mistake

Comment: I used the suggestion of @LenJaffe to update the answer.

Comment: @Borodin I used the same syntax of OP, my apologies for offending you.

Comment: @EricBouwers: I hope that was sarcastic? If not then please realise that you are not answerable to me. If so, then remember that Stack Overflow is all about creating crowd-sourced answers. SO itself says, *"Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them"*. I tend to make comments, as I did here, rather than modify solutions; but if I am sure that something is wrong I will amend it eventually. Thanks for your input here

Comment: @EricBouwers your previous answer was right . please update it as it was.

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident that administrative commands like that can work through `DBI` (and I can't test it at present) nor do I think you should be doing things that way, but I think the problem may be that the parameters to the command aren't quoted properly.

I suggest you change the command to this. At least it will make it more readable

```
$dbh1->do(<<'__END_SQL__');
CHANGE MASTER TO
  MASTER_HOST     = '54.254.154.33',
  MASTER_USER     = 'replica',
  MASTER_PASSWORD = 'aims145',
  MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin99',
  MASTER_LOG_POS  = 107
__END_SQL__
```